# Warning javac en Ubuntu

Tags: java

Estoy intentando compilar una `.java` y al hacer:

```
$ javac archivo.java
```

Aparece el siguiente warning:

```
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded
```

Tengo las siguientes versiones:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80
$ java -version
java 1.7.0_80
```

Por lo que no es error de tener un `javac` en una versión y `java` en otra.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Has verificado que no tienes más versiones de Java instaladas en tu computadora? Quizás las tengas pero en PATH aún apunta a la versión 1.7

Comment: Ya verifiqué la versiones de java y solo tengo la 7

Comment: ¿Y si sigues la recomendación y actualizas el JDK? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Pues no creo que esté relacionado a que las versiones sean distintas, simplemente te está recomendando que actualices el compilador (literalmente), sería buea idea que le sigas la corriente ;-)

Comment: Acabo de actualizarlo y se solucionaron los warnings, pero ahora a la hora de ejecutar indica: `A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`

Comment: ¿Por casualidad tienes algún archivo de configuración que utilices al momento de compilar tus archivos? Si existe dicho archivo, revisa si hay alguna versión de Java indicada allí.

Comment: no, no tengo ningún archivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ese error te sale porque el compilador de Java en Ubuntu no está actualizado. Nos muestras la version de javac (es decir, el lector), pero ¿tienes actualizado el SDK de java/openjdk? tienes que descargarte el JDK (java development kit), aparte del JRE, aqui tienes como hacerlo

http://www.ubuntu-guia.com/2012/04/instalar-oracle-java-7-en-ubuntu-1204.html